# gpsd stop when other process read gps device file

Tags: linux, device, gpsd

I have a Ubuntu computer with GPS device attachted at **/dev/ttyUSB3** and **gpsd** is running fine. When i try to read **/dev/ttyUSB3** from other process (e.g. **cat /dev/ttyUSB3**), gpsd does not work anymore. I have been try to start gpsd width debug option and got following error messages:

```
gpsd: INFO: closing GPS=/dev/ttyUSB3 (6)
gpsd: ERROR: select: Bad file descriptor
```

My gpsd version is: 3.11~dev

Can anyone tell me, why?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

When there are two processes read from the same tty device, they can interfere each other. (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-serial.devices.html)